# WPF : Making a nice menu - how to make an animation on some focus?

Tags: wpf

I'm quite new to the "nice" WPF application and until now I was very focused on the architecture part(MVVM and stuff). I'm looking to improve this and I'm trying some things.

Currently I'm trying to do this kind of menu:
[image]

Every element on the left would be triggering some action to navigate on the part on the right.

What I'm currently failing to achieve is the green part, because I would like that now, if I click on "Settings", the green element "move" to settings(in fact, move to the bound SelectedItem.

I'm not sure what is my best option to achieve this?

Comment: What control are you using for the menu?

Comment: I've not started the menu, my previous menus(without the green thing) is just a `StackPanel`, but I'm not sure that it is the best option here

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood the question... Are you wanting some sort of animation?

Comment: @GlenThomas Yes, I would like to have the green square making a transition to the correct element.

Comment: Oh... That's quite a big job. You should make an attempt at it first as its too big a question to answer here

Comment: I'm just looking for direction, because I don't know how to start

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListBox` control. Style the `ListBoxItem` to set a particular colour for the `HighlightBrushKey`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```